# How to add a FTPS network location in Windows 11?

Tags: windows, windows-11

Windows 11 (And previous version as well) allow adding a FTP network location but I don't see any way to a FTPS network location. When I enter FTPS instead of FTP, Windows tells me the URL seems invalid.

Please note the FTPS (FTP over SSL) is **NOT** at all the same thing as SFTP (FTP over SSH).

Also note that the question is related to creating a Windows `Network Location` not about using a FTPS client such as the excellent FileZilla. A FTP network location  is very similar to the way Windows handle ZIP files. The FTP (or FTPS or other Network Location) shows the files on the FTP server like local files in Windows Explorer. You can open, copy, drag&drop files using Windows Explorer.

To create a network location, open Windows Explorer and right click on "`This PC`" then in the popup menu click on "`Add a network location`". You can add a FTP server by using `ftp://myftpserver.com`. My question is "how to use `ftps://myftpsserver.com`.

Comment: Where are you doing and what ?

Comment: The person who linked my question to another one is confusing FTPS (FTP of SSL) and SFTP (FTP over SSH). They are totally different things. My question is NOT a duplicate.

Comment: That person is a moderator of this site and you need to convince him to undo it. My advice is to add much more information to your post, and also explain why this isn't a duplicate of the linked post. This change will automatically put your post in the review queue, so better wait a few days. After that, try to address him in a comment here using the `@name` syntax.

Comment: @harrymc thank for your explanation. I was totally aware of it. Here I only have small reputation but if you look on StackOverflow, you'll see that I have 11K reputation.

Comment: @fpiette I've reopened but please note that the duplicate question has an answer that says "the GUI File Explorer does not support it. A thirdparty software like WinSCP is currently the only way."

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks for the reopen. We'll see if someone has a solution.